# update system web optimization in web config

Tags: 2013, optimization

I am working on sp2013 -framework 4.5
I am trying to bundle and minify scripts and styles
1. can you recommend minifier to use in SharePoint.
2.

I am trying to add System.Web.Optimization to web.config 

I got :

> error CS0234: the type or namespace name "Optimization" does not
>   exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assemble
>   reference?)

tnx in advance :)
Ronen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nuget package to bundle assets, more detail [here](https://zoompf.com/blog/2015/01/automatically-optimize-css-javascript-asp-net)

Comment: I install via PM as suggested though when I update the namespace under web.config I got that error :

error CS0234: the type or namespace name "Optimization" does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assemble reference?)

Comment: could you check if this package is installed? Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization